# Are there any sample API without CORS?

Tags: python, ajax, rest, bokeh

Currently i need a sample API to test AjaxDataSource on my Bokeh project( checked all API from this one https://github.com/toddmotto/public-apis)

But all of them require Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

```
from datetime import date
from random import randint
from bokeh.models import AjaxDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn
from bokeh.models.layouts import WidgetBox
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import AjaxDataSource, CustomJS

adapter1 = CustomJS(code="""
    const result = {x: [], y: []}
    const json = cb_data.response
    console.log("Hi")
    for (var key in json) {
       if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          result.x.push(json[key].nome);
          result.y.push(json[key].codigo);
       }
    }
    console.log(result)
    return result
""")

source = AjaxDataSource(data_url='https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas', adapter = adapter1)

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="x", title="Nome"),
        TableColumn(field="y", title="Codigo"),
    ]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

show(data_table)
```

So i have this problem

[failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOaTA.png)

Are there any sample API that doesn't not require CORS out there?

Thanks

Comment: If the API is from a different origin (not on the same server) then I'd imagine it would virtually always use CORS, why not enable CORS to the specific API site you are using?

Comment: @SteveByrne CORS is a server thing, so if the site doesnt have CORS enabled, the OP wont be able to get around it, although i doubt that any API site would disable CORS

Comment: Sure, I was making the assumption his server (web host) was blocking CORS instead of the API, wouldn't that make more sense considering the API would be nearly, if not impossible to use without CORS --or am I miss understand CORS?--

Comment: @mast3rd3mon So there are no chance for me to test the code then ?

Comment: @BigAlligator only if CORS is enabled on the server you are calling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this api : https://www.geojs.io/docs/v1/endpoints/country/

e.g.

```
fetch("https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.json?ip=8.8.8.8")
  .then(function(data) {
    return data.json();
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this out: https://designer.mocky.io/design

Here you can design your own APIs for free.

Sample Code:

```
const axios = require("axios").default;
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://run.mocky.io/v3/7a7a924f-72dd-4cd7-aefa-12be3608e839',
};
 
axios.request(options).then(response => {
   console.log(response)
});
```

Comment: That is a pretty cool site. Thanks for your answer!